# Jquery Table Row Draggable and Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to provide both draggable and sortable function between 2 tables. I have provided 2 method which user can select files he can either drag and drop the files or he can double click the file and it will be added to the selected list. sample code is @ http://jsfiddle.net/fwjaj/. The issue I have is that when I double click and add the files I am able to sort them in the selected files table but when I drag and drop them I am unable to do it. What am I missing here? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot for your help.

Code below

**CSS**

```
div {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.draggable tbody td {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.draggable thead td {
    padding: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

tr.even {
    background-color: white;
}

tr.odd {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="width: 98%">
   <div style="width: 45%">
      <table id="tblFiles" style="width: 100%" class="draggable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Current Files
               </td>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr id="1">
               <td>File 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2">
               <td>File 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="3">
               <td>File 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="4">
               <td>File 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="5">
               <td>File 5
            </tr>
            <tr id="6">
               <td>File 6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="7">
               <td>File 7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="8">
               <td>File 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="9">
               <td>File 9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="10">
               <td>File 10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="11">
               <td>File 11</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div style="width: 45%; height: 300px; border:1px solid gray" id="divSelectedFiles">
      <table id="tblselectedFiles" style="width: 100%" class="draggable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Selected Files
               </td>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
function refreshTables() {
    $('#tblselectedFiles tbody,#tblFiles tbody').each(function () {
        $('tr:odd', this).addClass('odd').removeClass('even');
        $('tr:even', this).addClass('even').removeClass('odd');
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var c = {};
    refreshTables();
    $('#tblFiles tr').dblclick(function () {
        var tr = this.outerHTML;
        $(tr).addClass("selectedFiles");
        $("#tblselectedFiles tbody").prepend(tr);
        $(this).remove();
        $("#tblselectedFiles tbody tr").eq(0).effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
        refreshTables();
    });
    $("#tblFiles tr").draggable({
        //connectToSortable: '#tblselectedFiles tbody',
        helper: "original",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            c.tr = this;
            c.helper = ui.helper;
        }
    });
    var fixHelper = function (e, ui) {
        ui.children().each(function () {
            $(this).width($(this).width());
        });
        return ui;
    };
    $("#tblselectedFiles tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper
    });
    $("#tblselectedFiles tbody").disableSelection();
    $("#divSelectedFiles").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var $cTr = $(ui.draggable);
            $cTr.css("left", "");
            $cTr.css("top", "");
            if ($cTr.hasClass("selectedFiles"))
                return;
            $cTr.addClass("selectedFiles");
            $("#tblselectedFiles tbody").prepend($cTr);
            $cTr.effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
            refreshTables();
        }
    });
});
```

Maddy.

Comment: <script>
$('tbody').sortable();
</script>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could alternatively solve your problem like this :

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/fwjaj/4/

**JS**

```
$("#current-files").sortable({
    connectWith: "#selected-files"
});
$("#selected-files").sortable();

$("#current-files li").dblclick(function(ev){
    $(this).prependTo("#selected-files");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<h3>Current Files</h3>
<ul id="current-files">
    <li>File 1</li>
    <li>File 2</li>
    …

</ul>
</div>

<div>
<h3>Selected Files</h3>
<ul id="selected-files"></ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
…
li:nth-child(2n){
    background-color:#a6dbed;
}
…
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the answer to "what is the *right* way to solve this," but I do see a problem in your code.

The line in the click handler:

```
$("#tblselectedFiles tbody").prepend(tr);
```

Is not the same as the line in the drag handler:

```
$("#tblselectedFiles tbody").prepend($cTr);
```

In the first one, `tr` references outerHTML, and in the second, `$cTr` references a jQuery object.  If you convert the jQuery object into the same kind of object like this:

```
$cTr[0].outerHTML
```

it will work.  I tested it in your jsFiddle.

As for *why* this is true, I'll have to do some more thinking on this.

**EDIT:** I figured it out.  When you prepend the jQuery object as opposed to the String, it still has the draggable property attached to it.  You can remove this by calling

```
$cTr.draggable("destroy");
```

Comment: I made few changes to my code based on your suggestions. Now drag drop and then sorting is working fine but if I double click and add the file and then try to drag and drop it is not placing the tr correctly you can find my code here http://jsfiddle.net/fwjaj/11/. Also I see that when I drag the file I am unable to view it while dragging. Please help me out.

Comment: Take a look at rusln's answer, it's actually both simpler and better, taking more advantage of the built-in capabilities of jQuery UI.